# ng-repeat not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to pass a php Laravel array of objects with the name $event to my javascript part of the app and I am having issues with looping through the results later on.

Basically what I am doing is this

```
$events = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->orderBy('resolved', 'desc')->get(); //get events
    return View::make('events.index', compact('events')); //pass events to view
```

And then this is my view

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myevents = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($events) ?>');
    </script>


    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="checkboxController">


            <table class="table" id="keywords" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

                        <tr ng-repeat="event in myevents" >

                    <td> {{event.category}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>

                        </tr>
                </div>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="http://dsproject.dev:8000/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://dsproject.dev:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://dsproject.dev:8000/js/checkboxes.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my controller

```
var myApp2 = angular.module('myApp2',[]);

myApp2.controller('checkboxController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


    //var events = [];

   // $scope.some = 'hehehhehehe';
    //events.($scope.event);

    $scope.myevents = myevents;
    console.log($scope.myevents);

    /*$scope.toggle = function(id) {


        alert(id);
    };*/

}]);
```

The output I get is just {{event.category}} with no value at all. When I do console.log(myevents) or console.log($scope.myevents) in my controller I get the array of objects displayed in the console like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how would I fix this?

Comment: $scope.myevents = myevents;
This line links the $scope.myevents with the myevents var from php

i.e. var myevents = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($events) ?>'); this variable

Comment: Did you console.log "$scope.myevents" or set it as a global inside the controller "window.a = $scope.myevents;" and then check it in the console to make sure it's set?

Comment: Setting it as a global like that changed nothing :/.

Comment: My point was to check if it's set or not, by making it global it becomes a reference and as a reference it can be accessed later on even if the scoped variable changes. Was it set?

Comment: Were you able to solve this, I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The {{ curlies are being parsed by laravel, you have to change interpolation in angular.

```
 myApp2.config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
 });
```

and then use {[{ and }]} for the angular part of variables.

Comment: I did not use blade for the file extension. Do I still need to use interpolation?

Comment: no, you don't need to change it if you're not using blade - I guess (?)

Comment: Well from what I've seen people tend to either change interpolation in angular or blade, or use @{{}} - because that solves the problem of not being able to display angular variables in views, or they cut the blade extension which is that I did. But I cannot figure out why it won't print some simple data that is being looped.